# PDF form dropdown not fully populating with javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf, dropdown

Using javascript in a pdf form, I have a dropdown that references a location. When the user selects that location, the form is supposed to populate with information related to the location.

I have two issues:

1. The issue is that only ***some*** locations are populating with the information related to the location. I can't identify why. When I put the info into a javascript tester, it comes back with no errors.
2. I need the form to, when the user clicks on a blank location (as in, no location), the form clears any other information that populated from before. For example: I selected the location: Jasper and it populates with the Jasper information. But that was an error and I want to not have any information show up, I want to click on a blank in the drop-down and the form does not populate any information.

Thank you!
Cindy

[auto-populate](/questions/tagged/auto-populate)[javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)[pdf](/questions/tagged/pdf)[dropdown](/questions/tagged/dropdown)

I created a javascript using this article as my guide: https://acrobatusers.com/tutorials/change_another_field/

I expect that each location I put in to my form will populate the details necessary when that location is selected.

What actually happens is that only SOME of the locations are working.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! The issue was that I needed to put quotations around a few of the locations that had multiple words to their name.